# Angular2 check if object has peoperty inside *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-components, angular-ng-if

```
export interface Element {    
    name: string;   
}

export class Room implements Element {
name: string; 
type:string
}

export class Hall implements Element {
name: string;
}
```

and my varibale type is like below

```
selectedElement: Element;
```

now in html how can I check if the object is having property 'type' or not?

```
<div *ngIf="selectedElement?.type">
my div
</div>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess this should do what you want:

```
*ngIf="hasProp(selectedElement, 'type')"
```

```
hasProp(o, name) {
  return o.hasOwnProperty(name);
}
```

Comment: You can of course put that in a pipe as well to make it more reusable.

Comment: hasProp method returning false all the time. Any guess why?

Comment: I just tried it in the browser console and it works fine. What do you get when you add `console.log(o)` as first line inside `hasProp()`?

Comment: Thanks Gunter. It was my mistake, Its working perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it simply in the html:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedElement.hasOwnProperty('type')">
my div
</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngIf="selectedElement.hasOwnProperty('type');then 
showMyDiv">...</div>

<ng-template #showMyDiv> 
my div
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Using a function like that inside a template is not recommended. On change detection the method will be called each time. Using a pipe like suggested in @yannic his answer would be preferable (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64928306/1697459).

Answer (score 7):

in addition to what [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer) said:

```
*ngIf="selectedElement && selectedElement['type']"
```

Comment: I think this won't recognize `{type: null}` or `{type: 0}` or `{type: ''}`

Comment: yeah it won't recognize only {type: null}  or {type: ''} since `type` is `string`. but what he wants to do with `null` and an empty string.

Comment: Not sure, the question was to check if the object has a specific property, not if it has a value. I'm also not sure when this distinction is important. It depends on the use case I guess.

Answer (score 4):

A pipe would be the most performant option in that case.

Ts:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'hasProp',
})
export class HasPropPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(object: object, prop: string): boolean {
    return object.hasOwnProperty(prop);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<button *ngIf="option | hasProp: 'value'">Yay!</button>
```